# Possible Improvements for contact-form

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I followed the guide Building a contact form. And I added email notification additionally. My final code looks like this:

```
...

 // Email default "from" address for this module
 email: { from: 'XXX@gmail.com' },

 afterConstruct: function(self) {
   self.setSubmitSchema();
 },

 construct: function(self, options) {

   // build submit shema
   self.setSubmitSchema = function() {
     self.submitSchema = self.apos.schemas.subset(self.schema,
       [ 'name', 'email', 'title', 'body' ]
     );
   };

   // Submit request to piece
   self.submit = function(req, callback) {
     var piece = {};
     return async.series([
       convert,
       insert
     ], callback);
     function convert(callback) {
       return self.apos.schemas.convert(req, self.schema, 'form', req.body, piece, callback);
     }
     function insert(callback) {
       return self.insert(req, piece, { permissions: false }, callback);
     }

   };

   // Submit request by email
   self.afterInsert = function(req, piece, options, callback) {
     return self.email(req, 'emailInserted', {
         piece: piece
       }, {
         // can also specify from and other
         // valid properties for nodemailer messages here
         to: 'XXX@gmail.com',
         subject: 'A new suggestion was received'
       },
       callback
     );
   };

 }
};
```

Everything works like expected but I can't have the smtp login data for nodemailer in app.js laying around in the public code. That's my problem.

When I use this code without supply login form submission fails. Therefore I need either write additional if condition to trigger `self.afterInsert` only if valid login is supplied.

Or I would add login by `process.env.USER_SMTP`, `process.env.USER_LOGIN` and `process.env.USER_PW` in app.js if that works! But I would still have to add email `from:` and `to:` in `contact-form/index.js`. So I don't know really what's the polite way to solve this and I would appreciate some suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are experiencing some confusion about the security of putting things in JavaScript.

This is server-side (node.js) JavaScript code. Presumably located here:

```
/lib/modules/my-pieces-submit-widgets/index.js
```

That means it is just as secure as anything on your private server. It is not "public." No one can see it unless they have access to your server account.

If they have access to your server account they can already delete your entire database, turn your site into a spam generator, etc.

So I think you might be confusing this with what happens when you put credentials in browser-side JavaScript. In ApostropheCMS, that would mean putting them in a `public/js` folder. That is unsafe but you are not doing that here.

Assuming your code is in a private repository - which it should be - it is perfectly fine to put these credentials there. However yes there is no reason you cannot check `process.env.USER_SMTP` and so on if you prefer to do it that way. For instance, if you were planning to create a public npm module for other people to use in their projects, you might check such environment variables, or you might just tell people to set these properties in project level configuration.

If this does not clear up the question please provide more specifics as to why you are worried about this information getting out, and how.

Comment: I mean this source code: https://github.com/felixlberg/fullpage-cms

that's no private project. I made this to help other peeps to have easy website builder. I mean the public repostiory. I've tested around a little bit and was able to start with with env variables. I think that's the most flexible way...best thanks for your answer..sry I made the question a little bit early, I should have tested it extensively before...

Comment: Oh I see. That is an interesting project. Would you mind acknowledging Apostrophe's role in the README?

Comment: I will do and I will have an own section for apostrophe on live site as well. I want to promote apostrophe definitely because now since I started one year ago i can do almost everything what I want with apostrophe...so It will get definitely strong promotion on live site ;)